# R markdown code runs but I cannot get the code to knit/ keeps referring to 0 columns data frame -- when there are columns

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have inserted a CSV file into R markdown, and I have ran the code - everything works fine. However when I knit the code, there are repeated errors pertaining to the data frame which makes it seem as r markdown does not recognise the data frame. Perhaps I have missed something and I have missed a step but I cannot find any information on this.

Errors include -"can't rename cols that don't exist" or "can't assign names to a 0 column data.table", or "undefined columns selected

Apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious!

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
I upload library:

{r echo=FALSE}
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(base)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(broom)
library(psych)
library(readxl)
library(MASS)
library(htmltools)

Set working directory:
{r}
setwd

Read in data:
X<-fread(normalizePath("X.csv"))%>%clean_names()

Try to select columns I want using:
X<-X[,c((1:4),39,40,53,54,85,86)]

The above results in error when I try to knit (though when ran as code works)errors such as: "undefined columns selected"

I have also tried to rename using different versions such as:
colnames(X)[2] <- "name_1"
colnames(X)[3] <- "name_2" all of which work as normal r script but result in error when I try to knit errors include: can't rename cols that don't exist" or "can't assign names to a 0 column data.table"

Comment: You should simplify your document to almost nothing and then post the whole thing here.  We can't really guess what's wrong based on what you've shown us.

Comment: Welcome to SO! as @user2554330 was saying, it'll be easier to help if you can create a minimal reproducible example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Rmarkdown is generated in the folder that the doc exists in. You probably need to redirect to the data - the package `here` is a great opion a la `here::here("data", "X.csv")` - but yeah do what user said and make an actual example.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your help and suggestions. I will be sure to share a reproducible example in the future. Thank you for the link !

Comment: using here::here worked"! Thanks for this !